# Twitter authentication error "Authentication credentials are missing"

Tags: java, authentication, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have the following code for using the Twitter API in Java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterDataCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey(comsumerKey)
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
          .setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken)
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesstokensecret);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        //PrintWriter tweetWriter = null;
         twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");

        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" + status.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to authenticate to the Twitter API with consumer key and access token and trying to access my timeline but it is showing

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:186)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1554)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getHomeTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:105)
at TwitterDataCollector.main(TwitterDataCollector.java:24)
```

Answer (score 3):

The removal of the line

```
twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
```

Resolves your issue; `getInstance()` is returning you a `Twitter` using the auth details you specified in the `ConfigurationBuilder`.

If you want to use `getSingleton()` you will need to do some priming of the `ConfigurationContext` with your auth details. I'd hope that there is some documentation on how this should be done

On a side note I would reccommend not posting your OAuth keys to a public website